# How can I add a row within each step of a PHP prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, fetch

I have a prepared statement that produces a list of prices. The prices are determined by the value of the item multiplied by the quantity.

```
if ($select = $db -> prepare("SELECT value, quantity FROM items"))
{
    $select -> execute();
    $select -> bind_result($value, $quantity);
    while ($select -> fetch())
    {
        $subtotal = $value * $quantity;
        echo $subtotal.'<br />';
    }
    $select -> close();
}

// I want to put the $total here.
```

This outputs a list of numbers:

```
100
50
200
1.50
```

I would like to somehow add up each $subtotal and put them into another variable "$total" outside of my prepared statement. Is this possible to do WITHOUT doing the math within the query?

Comment: Mayhaps `$total += $subtotal;`?

Comment: Why are you using a prepared statement, without placeholders, in a context where it can't be reused?

Comment: @JuanTomas It's just a dumbed down example of what I was trying to accomplish. My actual code is more complex. Thank you though.

Comment: Thanks for trimming your code, then!

Comment: There's no need for `prepare()` or `execute()`; you can narrow that down to just `query()`. I don't know why you mention the words "prepared statement" in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare a variable `$total = 0` outside of the prepared statement and use it in the `while()` loop to calculate total price value, like this:

```
$total = 0;
if ($select = $db -> prepare("SELECT value, quantity FROM items")){
    $select->execute();
    $select->bind_result($value, $quantity);
    while($select -> fetch()){
        $subtotal = $value * $quantity;
        $total += $subtotal;
    }
    $select->close();
}
echo $total;
```

---

**Sidenote:** As @Fred-ii and @JuanTomas mentioned, since you're using prepared statement without any placeholders, you could change `->prepare()` to simply `->query()` while removing the `->execute()` statement altogether, it'll make no difference to your code.

Comment: Sidenote: Since they're not "preparing" anything *per se*, the `prepare()` can be changed to just `query()` while dropping `execute()` which makes for less code also ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to get at.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ,JuanTomas: I included a sidenote as well. But just my curiosity, would it be nice to keep the prepared statements as it is, just in case OP wants to play with placeholders in near future?

Comment: Thanks. I figured it was something stupidly simple like that. Here I was trying to add them all at once at the end and didn't even think to add them one at a time.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul It would, yet that would require a `WHERE` clause and a placeholder (as you know I'm sure) and if user input does get into the action; and the question's a bit unclear as to why they're using prepare here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah, little bit of blurriness in the question is still there. Hope OP will take note of the *sidenote*. ;-)

Comment: @RajdeepPaul They're probably using a prepared statement elsewhere and have used the results in the bind; who knows *lol*. It can be done as I've used that before, yet in this case it doesn't seem to be, but... I could be wrong. Oh well, the green tick speaks for itself ;-)